# minimized code for arrays in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

I have three arrays in js and now i want to add empty check on them..so please help me in short/ minimized code for the empty array check.My js code is

```
var selectedfirst = jQuery('select#frsts').val();
  var selectedsecond = jQuery('select#secnds').val();
  var selectedthird = jQuery('select#thirds').val();

  var lastfindal = selectedfirst.concat(selectedsecond); // Array concatination
  var getfinal = lastfindal.concat(selectedthird); // Array concatination
```

I know how can i process empty check on single array but due to contcatenation the code goes longer . i contcate first array to second then concate to third.I want to concate array when they are not empty. like `selectedfirst.length > 0`.if anyone not understand fully i will provide more detail on request.Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, because if you concat empty arrays, the result is an empty array. Ex: `[].concat([]).length === 0`

Comment: selectedfirst.concat(selectedsecond).concat(selectedthird);

Comment: @FritsvanCampen sorry for incomplete details.I want to concate arrays if they are not empty.

Comment: Since when does `.val()` return an array anyway?

Comment: if you want to concat two arrays...
concattedArray = concattedArray.concat(oldArray);

Comment: @kangoroo you are right but if you see my question i already did it.problem is when if array 1 or array 2 is empty ?

Comment: conditional ?
if(array != null) {concat}

Comment: @kangoroo yes conditional. if not empty then concate.

Comment: well there you go...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working i fix the issue.I created new array like

```
 var hege = [];
             if (selectedfirst!== null) {
                alert('not emtpy');
                var hege = hege.concat(selectedfirst);
             }
```

the same condition for other too.